# Cannot cast value of type MyClass to MyDelegate

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I have a class that needs to set a component to `self`. That component requires the class to implement a `protocol` *MyDelegate*. Eventually, it fails (SIGNAL SIGABRT).

```
// I need the class to be a NSObject for unrelated requirements 
class MyClass: NSObject {

// I force the compilation, but it then breaks apart at runtime anyway
 private let myComponent = 
 Component(requiresAnObjectofTypeMyDelegate: self as! MyDelegate) 
}

// in the same file 
 extension MyClass: MyDelegate {  
   func myUsefulDelegateCall() {
   } 
 }
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `self` inside the stored property `myComponent`.
Typically, it is not allowed to hand out `self` before the initializer has finished intializing the whole object. Therefore, your problem has nothing to do with protocols or extensions. More simple:

```
import Foundation


class Component {
    init(requiresAnObjectofTypeMyClass:MyClass) {
    }
}

// I need the class to be a NSObject for unrelated requirements 
class MyClass : NSObject {

    // I force the compilation, but it then breaks apart at runtime anyway
    private let  myComponent = 
        Component(requiresAnObjectofTypeMyClass : self as! MyClass)
}

let m = MyClass()
```

also crashes.

If you leave out the `NSObject` subclassing, you get a compiler error:

> use of unresolved identifier 'self'
>               Component(requiresAnObjectofTypeMyClass : self as! MyClass)

This shows the problem: You must not use `self` here.
I think it's just an Xcode bug; Xcode seems to ignore the syntax error when subclassing `NSObject`. The cast `as! MyClass` is also a hint that we are looking for a strange workaround that finally get's Xcode to it's knees and causes the runtime crash.

To work-around, you could create a lazy property, which will be evaluated after the initialization process and therefore will allow `self` to be handed into the `Component` initializer:

```
private(set) lazy var  myComponent = Component(requiresAnObjectofTypeMyClass:self)
```

Here, you also do not need the cast. Unfortunately, `lazy let` is not allowed in swift (and nobody knows why), so `private(set)` is close to it's semantic.

It's easy to transfer this code to your protocol example.

Comment: I feared that might be the case, but I'm always cautious about "this might demonstrate a xCode bug". 
I'll just lazy init then.

Answer (score 1):

A type cast is not needed. As `MyClass` adopts `MyDelegate` it ***is*** also `MyDelegate`.

And initialize the property lazily to be able to use `self` on the top level at all.

```
private lazy var myComponent = Component(requiresAnObjectofTypeMyDelegate: self)
```